# Lost reference to .net project

Tags: .net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm working on a project that uses C# code for the past few months, but this morning it has stopped working.

The project is still listed in the AOT

```
VisualStudio Projects/C Sharp Projects/AFD.AxIntegration
```

AFD.AxIntegration is also the namespace. However when I'm in the X++ editor there is no reference (up to now typing AFD the project would be listed in the Intellisence list). In fact I don't seem to be able to reference any of the projects listed.

The server is running on an Oracle VM VirturalBox. When I finished last night I saved the server, so theoretically it was initially at the same state it was yesterday.

I have tried:

- removing the project and re-attaching & deploying it to the AOT
- rebooted the server
- restarted the AOT service

I'm completely at a loss to see why it has suddenly stopped working this morning. Is there a setting that I may have accidentally changed?

Comment: I've just found that if I deploy the c# project in Release mode referencing works fine. The issue is only with Debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that if the .net code is compiled as 64 bit (x64) it cannot be referenced in X++. Compiling it as **Any CPU** or **x86** it works fine.